# How to turn fake players off in PES 2012 Master League mode?

Tags: pc, pro-evolution-soccer-2012

I've already managed to "unlock" well hidden option to actually have real players in Master League mode, but the fake (made up by Konami) players are still there and are even suggested when you for example go to the transfers. How to turn them off and leave only the real players, the authentic ones?

Comment: I don't think you can remove the "fake" players, but when you play with real line-ups the "fakes" will appear as youngsters in your second team. Which makes sense, as Konami cannot know which new players will appear in a year or two or five. Also, these players are the default master league team for year and they get older and develop (or decline) with each new PES, so they really feel like real life players after some time :)

Comment: @ivant That's not enough for me. Firstly - they appear not only as youngsters but also as grown ups in transfers, like I said before. Secondly - I don't want them at all! In previous version of PES they could always be turned off. I don't know what was Konami thinking forcing players to play with footballers made up by them? Why do they advertise the game with *real* fooballers then? Why do they advertise the game with *real* tournaments like Champions League and others? Please guys, find a way to fix this game!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... excellent question. I do it two months ago using the PES Editor 2012, that and change the teams on the official leagues (like spain). I like play Master League without classical players and in a "ficticious" league with all of the best teams (Barcelona, for eg) and you can't do it without moving / replacing / deleting teams and players.

[PES EDITOR from FifaCZ.com - Official Site](http://www.fifacz.com/editor.aspx)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your post. From what I can see this is a kind of a workaround, it's a shame they haven't provided us with an in-game option. However I cannot test it since I already deleted that game (I'm so glad that I decided to first download it to test it before buying it). Konami thinks that all work with the game will be done by fans, they just provide an engine and doesn't care. Ok, now let's go back to Diablo 3. :>

Comment: Thats the reason I played 2011 until right now and why they dont pay the rights for leagues like argentina / brazil / etc

Comment: @Lord_Blizzard could you provide an accepted answer? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have unlocked the option to use real players to start your master league, there's an option for you to start master league with real team lineup, instead of the default players.

Comment: If you can provide specific steps to get to that option, it would probably help other visitors to the site.

Comment: Start new master league, and you will see the option. People really need to be spoon fed huh?

Comment: revolver: I don't want to be rude but I wrote that I have already unlocked the real players and I have them in my team, there are real players in other teams **BUT** the fake players don't disappear from master league, they are still in the transfers! The question was _How to **turn off** fake players (completely)?_ and have only the real ones.

@DaveDuPlantis To turn on real players you need to have some (200?) points and you need to go to the "extra content" (wow, a basic functionality is an "extra content" now...) and you need to unlock I think _Master League mode 3_ or sth like that.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question then. If you are using the real lineup, those default players will be playing in PES united in some other lower division. That's why you still see them in your game. I don't think there's any ways to kill them off.

Comment: How did you unlock the real lineup because i can't find it anywhere

Comment: The option is not present. Please specify.